# I want soft key board when mobile is in landscape

Tags: android

In my application i want soft keyboard when emulator is in landscape mode only.if mobile is in portrait mode i want to use keyboard which was designed by me, give me some suggestions for this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at [InputMethodManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#hideSoftInputFromWindow%28android.os.IBinder,%20int%29), it will request to hide the soft input window from the context of the window that is currently accepting input